# vim forces indent if line begins with 'do'

Tags: vim

I use vim extensively, but sometimes when I type `gqip`, I find curious indentation in my paragraphs. For example, with the following snippet:

```
do not always run the tests and if they do,                                                                                                                       
an hour long
test suite tends to make developers less productive
when they have to wait a long time
for tests.
```

When I type `gqip`, I get this:

```
do not always run the tests and if they do, an hour long test suite tends to                                                                                      
    make developers less productive when they have to wait a long time for
    tests.
```

I am unsure why `do` triggers the subsequent line to be indented. Even hitting `enter` on a line beginning with `do` causes this, regardless of filetype.

How do I debug and fix this problem? I don't want to simply turn off auto-identing.

**Update**: Unsurprisingly, other words such as `while` and `for` also trigger this effect.

Comment: Post your `.vimrc`. You probably have configured a C indentation to work in every type of buffer which obviously leaves undesired side effects like this around.

Comment: What's your file's filetype? `:verbose set ft?`.

Comment: progo: I feel really stupid. That was it :)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> You probably have configured a C indentation to work in every type of buffer which obviously leaves undesired side effects like this around. – @progo

In general I have found that it is a good idea to qualify many options by putting them in filetype-specific autocommands. Editing paragraphs of text is just such a different beast than editing code.